# How to compile source

Tags: litecoin, compiling

I downloaded and install MinGW (windows). Then I downloaded Litecoin source from github. Now I use command:

```
make -f makefile.mingw
```

but I compilation stopped with this output:

```
C:\build\litecoin-master-0.8\src>make -f makefile.mingw
cd leveldb && make CC=cc CXX=g++ OPT="-mthreads -O2 -w -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -W
format-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -D_MT -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -DBOOST_THREAD
_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DUSE_IPV6=1 -I/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/s
rc/leveldb/include -I/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/helpers -I"/c/buil
d/litecoin-master-0.8/src" -I"/usr/local/include"" TARGET_OS=NATIVE_WINDOWS libl
eveldb.a libmemenv.a && cd ..
File not found - "*_bench.cc"
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb'
g++ -I. -I./include -fno-builtin-memcmp -D_REENTRANT -DOS_WINDOWS -DLEVELDB_PLAT
FORM_WINDOWS -DWINVER=0x0500 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -mthreads -O2 -w -Wall -
Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -D_MT -DWIN32 -D_WIND
OWS -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DUSE_IPV6=1 -I/c/build/lit
ecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/include -I/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/
helpers -I/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src -I/usr/local/include -c port/port_win
.cc -o port/port_win.o
rm -f libleveldb.a
ar -rs libleveldb.a port/port_win.o
c:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe: creating libleveldb.a
g++ -I. -I./include -fno-builtin-memcmp -D_REENTRANT -DOS_WINDOWS -DLEVELDB_PLAT
FORM_WINDOWS -DWINVER=0x0500 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -mthreads -O2 -w -Wall -
Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -D_MT -DWIN32 -D_WIND
OWS -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DUSE_IPV6=1 -I/c/build/lit
ecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/include -I/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/
helpers -I/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src -I/usr/local/include -c helpers/memen
v/memenv.cc -o helpers/memenv/memenv.o
rm -f libmemenv.a
ar -rs libmemenv.a helpers/memenv/memenv.o
c:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe: creating libmemenv.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb'
g++ -c -mthreads -O2 -w -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-par
ameter -g -D_MT -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADS
AFE -DUSE_IPV6=1 -I/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/include -I/c/build/l
itecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/helpers -I"/c/build/litecoin-master-0.8/src" -I"/
usr/local/include" -o obj/alert.o alert.cpp
alert.cpp:6:53: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp: No such
file or directory
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
                                                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/alert.o] Error 1

C:\build\litecoin-master-0.8\src>
```

Can someone please help me with compiling this source?

Comment: You also need to download and install [boost](http://www.boost.org/).